# Calling a Static Method from a Different Class (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, class, methods, cocos2d-iphone, call

I have a method called addEnemy in my class called Enemy, and I want to call this method in another class called EnemyLayer. I would use `[Enemy addEnemy];`, but it's not a static method (`-(void)addEnemy`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first import the `Enemy.h` file into your `EnemyLayer` file.  Then, create an instance of the `Enemy` class in your `EnemyLayer` file.  You can then call the `addEnemy` method on that instance:

```
[instanceOfEnemyClass addEnemy];
```

(in your example, you were trying to call the method on the entire `Enemy` class, but it's not a class method, so you have to call it on an instance of that class.)

Comment: They're both in the same class. When I do this, I get an error.
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1db5

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing EnemyLayer under Enemy ? 
Try to be more specific on your question.

Comment: Method addEnemy is in the Enemy class, and I want to use it in the EnemyLayer class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more code.  Your question is confusing.

I am thinking you want to know how to make a class method which is done like this:

```
+ (void) fooMethod
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

This method is not called on an instance of the class but on the class itself.  Therefore:

```
// Instance declaration
// The class is named FooClass and the instance of the class is _fooInstance
FooClass *_fooInstance;

// This will not work as it is calling for a 
// instance method which does not exist.
[_fooInstance fooMethod];

// This will work as it is calling for a class
// method which does exist.
[FooClass fooMethod];
```